# Depth Map three.js

Tags: dictionary, webgl, three.js, depth

Is there any way to obtain a depth map in three.js?

I am interested in producing something similar to what a Kinect would produce for a given scene.

I have come across a hacky way of using no colors and fog to mimic this but it would not be ideal because it would use two different scenes and would be variant to lighting.  Another way to do this I believe would be to access the depth buffer but it appears this cannot be accessed through three.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. Try using `MeshDepthMaterial`.